How does the 20-tester policy work if all testers do not join at the same time?
Does the 14-day count start only after all 20 testers join for the internal test? What would be the scenario if 15 testers were testing the app for 10 days and then the remaining 5 testers joined? Do the first 15 testers need to keep testing the app until the last 5 testers finish their 14 days of testing?

After 20 testers have joined, only then will the day's count start.
